# How to send mail in c# instantly or at least perform it in background

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am using smtp client and mail message class of c# in order to send mail. The mail is to be send to one or at most two users at a time. However, the mail sending process is slow. it takes almost 5-8 second to send mail. Till this time, the page remains in idle position. Is there a way in asp.net c# to send mail instantly or at least redirect to another page and perform the mail sending operation at background so that user do not feel delay. Any suggestions!! I had done research on smtpclient.sendmailAsync but in using this property, mail was not send.. Thanks in advance

Comment: You can always start a thread or async task to send the email so the page does not have to wait for it to be sent before returning

Comment: as i am new to this concept, I am not aware of how it is done.. can you provide some links from where i can use it..

Comment: thanks ken.. i got exactly what i wanted..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        Task sendEmail = new Task(() =>
        {
            //create the mail message
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            //set the addresses
            mail.From = new MailAddress("me@mycompany.com");
            mail.To.Add("you@yourcompany.com");

            //set the content
            mail.Subject = "This is an email";
            mail.Body = "this is a sample body";

            //send the message
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Port = 465;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("youGmailAddress@gmail.com", "YourPassword");  

            smtp.Send(mail);
        });

        sendEmail.Start();
```